# PHP uploading multiple images and inserting into database

Tags: php

i want the user to be able to upload multiple images. Is there a way to store the paths of say 3 images under one field in the database? I mean having all of the image paths in the same column like so

```
Images                                                     | date                                                                               
images/file1.jpg, images/file2.jpg, images/file3.jpg       | Thursday...

<ul id="image_upload">
    &lt;input type="file" name="image[]"&gt;&lt;a href="#" id="add_more">Add more</a> <br>
     [removed]
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#add_more').click(function(){
        var current_count = $('input[type="file"]').length;
        var next_count = current_count + 1;
        $('#image_upload').append('<br>&lt;input type="file" name="image[' + next_count + ']"&gt;&lt;br>');
       });
      });



    </ul> <br><br>
```

then i check the files with php and attempt to insert to the database

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image'])){  
  for ($i = 0; isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]); $i++) {
   $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
   $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
   $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
   $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

   if (!in_array($fileExt, $allowed)) {
    $errors[] = 'Incorrect file type. Only allowed: ' . implode(', ', $allowed) . '';
   }
   if ($fileSize > 2097152) {
    $errors[] = "$fileName exceeds the maximum file size of 2 MB";
   }
  }

  for ($i = 0; isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]); $i++) {
   $fileBase = basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
   $fileName = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $fileExt = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $fileTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
   $fileDst = 'images/images/'.basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
   for ($j = 0; file_exists($fileDst); $j++) {
    $fileDst = "images/images/$fileName-$j.$fileExt";
   }
   if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDst)) {
    $output[$fileBase] = "Stored $fileBase OK";
   } 
  }
 }
```

this code only uploads the first image to the temp folder and only one path into the database

Comment: use var_dump() or print_r() to know what exactly you have in the $_FILES variable

Comment: comma or a pipe separated value will do it for you..make sure you parse it when you want to use it

Comment: move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDst&#41;&#41;  ?

Comment: print_r($fileDst); just gives me one image path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Upload all images at once :

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmImgUpload">
    <input name="multiple_uploaded_files[]" type="file" multiple="true" />
</form>

foreach ($_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name'] as $file)
    {
        print_r($file);
        //use the move_uploaded_file() to move your file on your server directory.

        //fire an insert query that inserts all the file names with comma separated value
    }
```

### IF you want the user to upload images separately,one by one :

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]" id="file" >
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]" id="file" >
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]" id="file" >

foreach ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'] as $file)
        {
            print_r($file);
            //use the move_uploaded_file() to move your file on your server directory.
            //fire an insert query that inserts all the file names with comma separated value
        }
```

Comment: but that way you can select multiple at once from the browse window where as i want the user to manually to upload one by one

Comment: well than have multiple input type=file..it doesnt get simpler

Comment: okay i guess i could do that and to have an Add more button ill just hide the reset of the inputs and add one by one on each click right?

Comment: okay that seemed to work. now once they are in the database i just call them like so <img src="$file"> and loop until all loaded?

Comment: naaa..you need to parse the string you stored..coz you are storing multiple file names in one field.So when you get the string...explode() the string with your separator..and store it in an array.then loop over it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47479/discussion-between-bamba-and-time-to-leave-earth)

Answer (score 1):

You just remove the index from dynamic file elements, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_more').click(function(){
        $('#image_upload').append('<br><input type="file" name="image[]" />');
    });
});
```

There is no need to provide the indexing. Just provide an array symbol `[]` only. Your problem here is that you've given an index of 2 to the first dynamic file. So the file array indexes becomes 0, 2, 3 etc, so the loop will fail to iterate properly.

Comment: when i did print_r($fileDst); i only got one image path

Comment: The index of the first file element is 0. Then next must be 1. But as per your jquery you given it 2. Then in your for loop condition second iteration becomes false. So only one image is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the paths, I would take a look at [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).  They are made to create storeable representations of data.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to store the paths of say 3 images under one field in the database?

There are at least 3 ways for doing it:

1. [Serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) PHP array before save it into your database and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) after select.
2. Save them as a string with some separator (for example: path1||path2||pathX). Implode and explode functions would be helpful.
3. If you are using PostgreSQL you can just use array datatype. So you will be able to manipulate them in SQL (counting, change one of them to another etc.).

But I think it's not a better way for solving this issue. Because now you want to save only a path, after a couple of days you might want to add some extra data like an ALT text, title, description, size, path to small preview etc.

So using some "user_images" table would be more convenient.