# codeigniter insert multiple image into different database fields

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

if i insert into database i want two image to be inserted in to different fields in the database example 
image1_name        image2_name
first image here    second image here
i only know how to insert one

**controller**:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2000';
    $config['max_width'] = '2000';
    $config['max_height'] = '2000';
    $config['new_image'] = './assets/';

    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Category Name', 'required');
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload() || !$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->session->set_flashdata("message2","Product not added");
        redirect('add_products','refresh');
    } else {

        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $this->thumb($data);


        $file = array(
            'img_name' => $data['raw_name'],
            'thumb_name' => $data['raw_name'] . '_thumb',
            'ext' => $data['file_ext'],
            'category' =>$this->input->post('name')


            );
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        if($this->User->insert_cat($file) === TRUE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message","You Have Successfully Added a new Category!");
            redirect('add_category','refresh');
        }else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message2","Category not added");
            redirect('add_category','refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

**view**:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('add_new_category/do_upload');?>
        <center>
        <?php if (validation_errors()): ?>

            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="width: 700px;">
                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style=" color: white"></label>

            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="userfile">
            </div>

        </div>
        <br> <br> <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style=" color: white"></label>

            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. coffee"
                name="name"
                value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
            </div>

        </div>
```

**model**:

```
public function insert_cat($file)
{
    // $this->db->insert('product_table',$file);
    if($this->db->insert('product_category', $file))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see only one image input file on your view.... You want to upload multiple image from same input file ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP uploading multiple images and inserting into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772358/php-uploading-multiple-images-and-inserting-into-database)

Comment: havent tried the multiple uploading so it has only one, I want to upload two images separetly into two different fields in database

Answer (score 0):

Add one more function in model

```
    public function insert_cat1($file){
            $this->db->insert('product_table',$file);

           {
                return TRUE;
           }else
           {
              return FALSE;
          }
        } 

And change the controller


    function do_upload() {
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2000';
            $config['max_width'] = '2000';
            $config['max_height'] = '2000';
            $config['new_image'] = './assets/';

            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Category Name', 'required');
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload() || !$this->form_validation->run()) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata("message2","Product not added");
             redirect('add_products','refresh');
            } else {

                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $this->thumb($data);


                $file = array(
                    'img_name' => $data['raw_name'],
                    'thumb_name' => $data['raw_name'] . '_thumb',
                    'ext' => $data['file_ext'],
                    'category' =>$this->input->post('name')  


                );
                  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                 $insert1=$this->User->insert_cat($file);
                 $insert2=$this->User->insert_cat1($file);
               if(($insert1)&&($insert2)==TRUE)
         {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message","You Have Successfully Added a new Category!");
            redirect('add_category','refresh');
         }else
         {
             $this->session->set_flashdata("message2","Category not added");
             redirect('add_category','refresh');
          }
          }
          }
```

Comment: not working for me it just add the first image to both the two fields

Comment: you insert $file in both tables

Comment: they are on the same table just with different field